# get traffic class of a udp packet using python socket

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I want to retrieve the traffic class(TOS) of a udp packet using python sockets. Following code makes the socket in python, and i want to retrieve its traffic class similar to (getTrafficClass method in java sockets).

```js
UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
UDP_PORT = 8080
BUFFER_SIZE = 20

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
data, address = s.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
if data:
  print "received data:", data
  //I need to get the traffic class here.
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no ready method like `getTrafficClass()` in java. you can read the IP layer header (one below the UDP layer header) and parse it, example code is in `Sniffy.py` https://github.com/OffensivePython/Sniffy/blob/master/Sniffy.py or https://codingsec.net/2016/05/decoding-ip-layer-python/

```
[...]
def sniff(sock):
""" sniff a packet, parse its header and dump the sniffed data """
packet, address = sock.recvfrom(65565)
ipheader=ip(packet[:20])
ipheader.parse()
[...]
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass%28int%29, This is the link to the method that is specified in java docs. I want something like this.